# Using VBA to connect Access to Excel, will not output any records from Access

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I would like to connect to my Access tables using VBA. I want to be able to type in a purchase order number, and reference that value in a query to the Access table. I want to print the results of that query to my Excel worksheet. This is what I have so far.. any ideas?

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim myValue As Variant
myValue = InputBox("Enter Purchase Order Number:")
Range("A1").Value = myValue

Call ADO_Conn(myValue)
End Sub


Sub ADO_Conn(myValue)
Dim conn As New Connection
Dim rstAnswer As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim connected As Boolean
Dim RootPath, DBPath As String
Dim tempString As String

 connected = False

RootPath = "Z:\BSD Internship Program\FY14 Intern Files\John Jameson\Vouchers"
DBPath = RootPath & "Acquisition Support Datamart Build 9.11-03.accdb"
conn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source= Z:\BSD Internship     Program\FY14 Intern Files\John Jameson\Vouchers\Acquisition Support Datamart 9.1103.accdb;"

connected = True

rstAnswer.Open "SELECT VW_PUB_PURCHASE_ORDER.PO_NO FROM VW_PUB_PURCHASE_ORDER " & _
"WHERE VW_PUB_PURCHASE_ORDER.PO_NO = ' " & myValue & " ';", conn, adOpenKeyset,       adLockOptimistic

Do Until rstAnswer.EOF
tempString = CStr(rstAnswer!VW_PUB_PURCHASE_ORDER)
Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A5").Value = tempString
rstAnswer.MoveNext
Loop

rstAnswer.Close
conn.Close
connected = False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things about your initial query:

```
rstAnswer.Open "SELECT VW_PUB_PURCHASE_ORDER.PO_NO FROM VW_PUB_PURCHASE_ORDER " & _
"WHERE VW_PUB_PURCHASE_ORDER.PO_NO = ' " & myValue & " ';", conn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
```

You are searching only for PO_NO in this query, so that is the only value that will return.  If you want more than just that data (as I assume you might), then you want this:

```
rstAnswer.Open "SELECT * FROM VW_PUB_PURCHASE_ORDER " & _
"WHERE VW_PUB_PURCHASE_ORDER.PO_NO = ' " & myValue & " ';", conn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
```

... where the asterisk means "all".

In addition, this bit concerns me:

```
' " & myValue & " '
```

You are adding leading and trailing blanks to your search term.  This may or may not be what you want, but I assume that you do not want this.  You probably want:

```
'" & myValue & "'
```

And if your PO_NO is a numeric value, you need to omit the apostrophes:

```
" & myValue & "
```

Lastly, I don't think you want to loop at all.  The SELECT query will return all the results without requiring you to iterate rows.  Maybe you should try getting rid of your "do" loop and using this instead:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A5").CopyFromRecordset rstAnswer
```

Your query values will then be dropped into a dynamic range starting at the designated sheet & cell.

I didn't test the code so I might not have caught everything, but those jumped out at me.

Hope that helps!

Nate

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! Getting rid of the loop was a great idea. Do you know of a way to reference cell A1 instead of using myValue. I have tried "WHERE PO_NO = '&Sheet1.Range(A1).Value';" but it doesn't seem to work. Any insight?

Comment: Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") ought to do the trick.  If you don't enclose "A1" in quotes Excel will consider it a variable.

Comment: For some reason VBA isn't liking ("A1").. I think it's " " that's causing problems! I'm so close though!

Comment: Are you getting an error message or is it just not returning any results?

Comment: It gives me a compile error (expected: end of statement)

Comment: And the query works fine in Access for the same PO_NO that you are searching for?

Comment: And it works fine when I hard code in the PO number!

Comment: Enclosing the PO in this way: -'" & myValue & "'- is for strings, not numeric values.  If your PO number is an integer or a long, then you need to omit the apostrophes, like such -" & myValue & "-.  Do you see the difference?

Comment: It still didn't work.. I've tried making myValue a String and a Long and it won't output anything!

Comment: Post an example of what works, like this:  *rstAnswer.Open "SELECT * FROM VW_PUB_PURCHASE_ORDER " & _
"WHERE VW_PUB_PURCHASE_ORDER.PO_NO = 123456;", conn, adOpenKeyset,*

Comment: rstAnswer.Open "SELECT PO_NO  FROM VW_PUB_PURCHASE_ORDER " & _
"WHERE PO_NO = '0000111672';", conn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic

Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("G2").CopyFromRecordset rstAnswer

Comment: OK, you need your data to be a string because of those leading zeroes.  You definitely need to format as a String as opposed to a numeric value, include apostrophes, and make sure the input box contains all those leading zeroes.  They aren't optional.  If that doesn't work you might try *"WHERE VW_PUB_PURCHASE_ORDER.PO_NO LIKE %'" & myValue & "'%;"* instead of *"WHERE VW_PUB_PURCHASE_ORDER.PO_NO = '" & myValue & "';"*

Comment: I figured it out!! I needed there to be spacing EVERYWHERE: WHERE W_PUB_PURCHASE_ORDER.PO_NO = ' " & myValue & " ';"   We were SO CLOSE! Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: You bet!  Please flag this as answered!